# .hover() and .append() appends multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got this code:

```
$(".l-definition").on({
  mouseenter : function() {
    var definition = $(".l-definition").attr('data-label');
    $(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
    $(".definition").show(300);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(".definition").hide(300);
  }
});
```

to append an item on hover using jQuery.
Sometimes it adds that item multiple times, because the cursor hovers the element multiple times accidentaly, which occurs in visual bugs with `.show()` and `.hide()`.
How can I prevent jQuery from doing that?
Here's a snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".l-definition").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      var definition = $(".l-definition").attr('data-label');
      $(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
      $(".definition").fadeIn(300);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(".definition").fadeOut(300);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.definition {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -70%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #ededed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.definition::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #e8e8e8;
  clear: both;
}

.l-definition {
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing <span class="l-definition" data-label="Chromium is a chemical element">Chromium</span></p>
```

Comment: Show HTML structure. Also why to append `.definition` every time?

Comment: You are always adding new divs. Never checking for existance beforehand. Never remove.

Comment: Maybe a bit hacky but: Could it work with some sort of variable/data which is set when mouseenter occured? Like `actionHappened = true` and `if ( actionHappened ) return;`

Comment: @Justinas added that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you are doing is showing a tooltip, why not use the `after` pseudo selector, then you will not need any jquery.

I have commented the code below

```css
p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.l-definition:after {
  content: attr(data-label);   /* use attr for text */
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -10px;                  /* minus height of arrow */
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #ededed;
  opacity:0;                   /* opacity */
  transition: opacity 0.3s;    /* transition opacity over 300ms */
  pointer-events:none;         /* this is so you can mouse things under hidden tooltip */
  
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.l-definition::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #e8e8e8;
  clear: both;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0;
}

.l-definition:hover:after,    /* change opacity to 1 when hovered */
.l-definition:hover:before{
   opacity:1;
   pointer-events:auto;
}

.l-definition {
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing <span class="l-definition" data-label="Chromium is a chemical element">Chromium</span></p>
```

If you want to stick with using jQuery, then I would do it like this:

```js
$(".l-definition").each(function() {
  var label = $(this),
    definition = $('<div class="definition">' + label.data('label') + '</div>');  // cache these objects for better performance

  label.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      label.append(definition.fadeIn(300));  // append definition and fade in
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      definition.fadeOut(300, function() {  // fadeout definition and then remove once animation complete
         $(this).remove();            
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.definition {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -70%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #ededed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}

.definition::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #e8e8e8;
  clear: both;
}

.l-definition {
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing <span class="l-definition" data-label="Chromium is a chemical element">Chromium</span></p>
```

Comment: Didn't know that you can use `attr(data-label);` with the `content` property! Nice solution, but I prefer, that the elements get completely hidden (`display:none`) instead of just `opacity:0` (and still get a fading effect). But thanks! Learned something new :)

Comment: No problems, just so you know though `opacity:0` with `pointer-events:none` is just the same as `display:none` - ie it is hidden and the mouse won't interact with it.  But I have also added a js solution

Comment: You can use visibility:hidden to achieve the same effect on positioned elements.

Comment: @OndraKoupil Don't think it will transition opacity if you use either visibility hidden or display none

Comment: @OndraKoupil I stand corrected, it's only display that doesn't allow opacity transitions: https://jsfiddle.net/0mc1sh3e/

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your help :) There were alot of good answers but yours was the most explaining imo, so I accepted yours

Comment: @Pete It will, it is the magic of transitioning visibility. Visibility is animatable, while display is not. So if you transition display, the change is instant. If you transition visibility, it will appear instantly (with opacity 0 and then fade in) and hide at the very end of transition duration (while opacity transition makes it fade out).

Answer (score 2):

Could you check does the `definition` tag already exists, like:

```
if ($(this).find('.definition').length<=0) 
    $(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
```

Also added `stop(true,true)` to stop previously animation.

```
$(".definition").stop(true,true).show(300);
```

**I were also fixed it so it works with more definitions, because you forgot to use `$(this)` and all definitions were triggered on mouseover/out.!**

**Demo with fixes:**

```js
$(".l-definition").on({
  mouseenter : function() {
    var definition = $(this).attr('data-label');
    if ($(this).find('.definition').length<=0)
        $(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
    $(this).find(".definition").stop(true,true).show(300);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).find(".definition").hide(300);
  }
});
```

```css
p{
margin-top:100px;
}
.definition{
 display:none;
 padding:5px 10px;
 border-radius:5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: -70%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size:.8em;
  font-weight:300;
  background-color: #ededed;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
.definition::after{
 content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #e8e8e8;
  clear: both;
}
.l-definition{
 font-weight: 600;
 cursor:pointer;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consetetur sadipscing <span class="l-definition" data-label="Chromium is a chemical element">Chromium</span></p>
<span class="l-definition" data-label="You were creating duplicate definition, but never checked does it already exists (or remove before append).">What was wrong?</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! Working perfectly! Just wondering: Why does this if condition work without the `{ }`?

Comment: Because it's one line, if i used more then one line i would use brackets `{ }`

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I always use these brackets `{ }`

Comment: It's isn't really matter, but if you use it, continue with the same technique :)
But don't forget that in this code, i were changed all code inside $('.l-definition') to `$(this)` so it will work just for hovered not for all!
 Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

You do want to maintain the **`context`** of the element on which the event occurs otherwise you'll always be getting the `label` of the first and applying your operations on all such elements, if you have multiple elements with the same class.

Therefore, change:

```
var definition = $(".l-definition").attr('data-label');
```

To:

```
var definition = $(this).data('label'); //also take advantage of the data method.
```

You may also consider changing:

```
$(".definition").....
```

To:

```
$(".definition", this).....
```

If you do not wish to operate on all existing `.definition` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Call `.stop()` to stop any ongoing animations, and make sure you `.remove()` the added content.

But I would suggest a better way. Right now you have:

```
<div class="l-definition" data-label="Label text">Main text</div>
```

But why not do something like this?

```
<div class="l-definition">
  Main text
  <div class="definition">Label text</div>
</div>
```

+ CSS:

```
.l-definition>.definition {
    display: none;
    animation: fade 300ms linear both;
}
.l-definition:hover>.definition {
    display: block;
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: 0}
    to   {opacity: 1}
}
```

This gets the job done much better, with better support for things like search engines and text-only browsers!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".l-definition").on({
  mouseenter : function() {
    var definition = $(".l-definition").attr('data-label');
    if (!$(this).find('.definition').length) {
      $(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
      $(".definition").show(300);
    }

  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(".definition").hide(300);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just clear them before appending new

```
$(".definition").remove();
$(this).append("<div class='definition'>" + definition + "</div>");
```